# Why so many `.`firebug`-like word on the downloaded web page?

Tags: html

A web page contains so many  `.firebug`-like class after downloading it on my local directory.

```
.firebugLayoutBoxParent {
border-top: 0 none !important;
border-right: 1px dashed #E00 !important;
border-bottom: 1px dashed #E00 !important;
border-left: 0 none !important;
position: fixed !important;
width: auto !important;
}
.firebugRuler{
position: absolute !important;
}
```

Why the `.firebugLayoutBoxParent` do not exist in online status,that is to say `.firebugLayoutBoxParent` can't be seen by firebug,it do not exist at all in online status,`.firebugLayoutBoxParent` can only be seen after downloading it into local directory and open it with some kind of text editor?

Comment: It is unclear what you ask. What do you mean by "can't be seen"?

Comment: My guess it's because when you download a page, it grab all the css and since you have firebug, it grabs those classes as well. I don't think this is something you should worry about